# Choose image Source path from resourcedictionary

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a checkbox, that I style with custom images.
I need to choose an image at runtime, depending on theme.
I want to just change image and not all template.
This is my checkbox's template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="FlatCheckbox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="/checked.png" Width="32"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="checkboxImage" Property="Source" Value="/unchecked.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

So I want to take just the path of Source of checkboxImage from ResourceDictionary( which I can choose in runtime.)
For example if I could put a key ImagePath in ResourceDictionary and use something like this

```
<Image x:Name="checkboxImage" Source="{ImagePath}" Width="32"/>
```

How to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may declare a BitmapImage as XAML resource and reference it as `DynamicResource`, e.g. like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="TestImage" UriSource="Image1.jpg"/>
    <Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource TestImage}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Then you can replace the resource by some other BitmapImage like

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Resources["TestImage"] =
        new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Image2.jpg"));
}
```